# How do I do an incremental search in word 2007?

Tags: search, microsoft-word-2007

Sounds like a straight forward problem, but I cannot find a proper solution. Ctrl+f only gives the search dialog box and it doesn't have an incremental search option. I cannot find  away to open the navigation panel (not sure if it exists in Word 2007). The document map does not have a search function.

How can I do an incremental search in Word 2007? Is it even possible?

Comment: Click View -> Document Map to open the navigation pane.

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of what you want?  Every change to a search term in Word results in a new search, so I am not sure what an incremental search is.